# Some occurrence of \r\n not working in text email encoding in one of the test environments

Tags: java, email, newline

I am trying to generate a message in Java for an email. The generated email works fine in Dev and test environment, But UAT is not detecting some of EOL, In same email few occurrences are working and Some are not working. Please find below the code to get the Email Message:

```
String genMessage(Suport me) {
    public String EOL = "\r\n";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(EOL);
    sb.append(EOL);
    sb.append("The item below is now travelling");
    sb.append(EOL);
    sb.append("Reason for the delay: ");
    sb.append(me.getReason());
    sb.append(EOL);
    sb.append("item Number: " + meBO.getId());
    sb.append(EOL);
    ReferenceBO deliveryNumber = me.getDNumber();
    sb.append("Del Number: " + (dNumber != null ? deliveryNumber.getValue() : ""));
    sb.append(EOL);
    sb.append(EOL);
    sb.append("Carrier: " + me.getCarrier() + " - " + me.getCarrierName());
    sb.append(EOL);
    sb.append(EOL);

    sb.append("Original Delivery Date/Time: E: " + getDate(me.getEarliestDelDatetime())));
    sb.append(EOL);
    sb.append("Original Delivery Date/Time: L: " + getDate(me.getLatestDelDatetime())));
    sb.append(EOL);

    return sb.toString();
```

}

The Email generated :

The item below is now travelling
Reason for the delay: Vehicle breakdown or accident item Number: 644812 Del Number: TEST20170925

Carrier: ABC - ABC EXPRESS, PVT LTD.

Original Delivery Date/Time: E: September 27, 2017 8:00 AM Original Delivery Date/Time: L: September 27, 2017 5:00 PM

So, here after **1st line** and also before and after **Carrier:** EOL looks to be working but not at other places. 
Any Suggestion will be Helpful.

Comment: What operating system are you on and are UAT using the same? Is the application installed locally? If so, use: System.lineSeparator()

Comment: Yes, As per info available all are windows 10, We have tried System.lineSeparator(), Even that is not working well.

Comment: Potential solution here: "Indent each line three or more spaces.
That will tell a receiving copy of Outlook not to mess with the line breaks". Let me know if it works. Link: http://support.xink.io/support/solutions/articles/1000064098-why-is-outlook-stripping-line-breaks-from-plain-text-emails

Comment: From various sources: Adding 3 spaces the the beginning or end of a line should stop outlook doing funky things to your line spaces. So try setting EOL = "   \r\n". (3 spaces prefix)

Comment: @MaxBilbow Thanks for the suggestions, May be Outlooking is messing with the response, Will push it and Update the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your solution @maxBilbow.

The issue was due to Outlook changing the format and ignoring some of the line changes and spaces it assumed unnecessary.

Adding 3 or more spaces at the start of each line fixed the issue.

replaced **public String EOL = "\r\n";** with **public String EOL = "\r\n     ";**